# regex to match value up to 2 decimal

Tags: regex

I want to have 1 to 5 digits only before the "." and 0 to 2 digits after the "." 
this is what I have so far for regex.

```
^\d{1,5}\.?\d{0,2}$

1.00 -- match
11.01 -- match
111.10 -- match
1111.52 -- match
11111.23 -- match
.12 -- no match ... want to match
123456 -- match ... don't want to match because can take up to 5 integers before decimal
1234567 -- match ... don't want to match because can take up to 5 integers before decimal
```

can anyone help?

Comment: I use this tool to tinker with REGEXs [RegEx Builder](http://renschler.net/RegexBuilder/).  Works like a dream

Comment: For fast online regex tests I suggest using http://regexpad.com/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need an alternative between numbers with decimal point and numbers without:

```
^\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.\d{1,2}$
```

**Edit:**

Thanks to user1884032 for pointing out the missing parentheses:

```
^(\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.\d{1,2})$
```

Comment: I've used what you suggested and put in 4567891, it's still saying that it's a match which it shouldn't.

Comment: I tried it on http://regexpal.com/ and my suggestion works... the regex can only match 7 digits if there is a dot after the fifth digit. Did you check for typos?

Comment: added the parentheses and it worked. ^(\d{1,5}|\d{0,5}\.\d{1,2})$

Answer (score 1):

```
 /^(\d{0,5}\.\d{1,2}|\d{1,5})$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this:

```
^\d{1,5}\.\d{0,2}$
```

I've removed the `?`, which was making the dot optional.

Saying you want to match `.12` contradicts your spec - that doesn't have 1-5 digits before the dot.  Did you mean `{0-5}`?

Answer (score 0):

Better late than never:

```
^([\d]{0,5})(\.[\d]{1,2})?$
```

Two groups:

- One matching from 0 up to 5 digits,
- The other from 1 up to 2 decimals, allowing `0.12` as `.12`.

Simple and perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I achieved in python3 is this -

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'^\d{2}.\d{2}')
print(p.findall('12.59, 11.789, 10.6 lords a-leaping'))
```

output - `['12.59']`

Answer (score -1):

There are two separate issues:

1. If you want to match 0 to 5 digits before the "." so you'll need the first part to say `d{0,5}` instead of `d{1,5}`.
2. Instead of having an optional "." followed by two more characters, you should have the "." if there are characters after it, but no dot if there are no characters after it.  With the following, you will only end up with seven digits if the last two come after the "."

   `^\(d{0,5}\.\d{0,2})|(d{0,5}\.?)$`

which means

EITHER
  0-5 digits, then a decimal point, then 0-2 more digits
OR
  0-5 digits, followed by an optional decimal point

This format will also detect legitimate numbers within that range that you didn't list in your test, such as `12345.` and `0.12`

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
/^\d{0,5}\.\d{0,2}$/
```